# Why do some Scala methods use polymorphic arguments instead of using Any/Nothing?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, any

For example, [`Exception.allCatch`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception%24) is defined as

```
def allCatch[T]: Catch[T]
```

Why not just

```
val allCatch: Catch[Nothing]
```

when `Catch` is covariant in its argument?

Or, why [`PartialFunction`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction%24) object defines

```
def empty[A, B]: PartialFunction[A, B]
```

instead of just

```
val empty: PartialFunction[Any,Nothing]
```

?

**Update:** So far it seems that the answers miss the point. So please include a specific examples in your answer that really target the question. For example: Show a piece of code that works with `def empty[A, B]: PartialFunction[A, B]` but doesn't work (or is less convenient) with `val empty: PartialFunction[Any,Nothing]`.

Comment: I think you should update your question to include why it matters.

Comment: @nilskp I'm curious about the design of the libraries. In particular, when I create my own code, should I use polymorphic variants or those with `Any/Nothing`?

Answer (score 2):

This saves the need for casting later and allows to treat the args type as T instead of Any, which is usually more convenient.

Here is an example:

```
scala> def func1[T](arg : T) : T = { arg }
func1: [T](arg : T)T

scala> def func2(arg : Any) : Any = { arg }
func2: (arg: Any)Any

scala> func1(4)
res4: Int = 4

scala> func2(4)
res7: Any = 4
```

Comment: Your example is correct, no doubts, but it doesn't answer my question. It involves an invariant type parameter - you could rephrase it as `def func1[T]: T => T = (arg: T) => arg`. Here of course we cannot avoid the type parameter - any such attempt would make the function less general. But my question targets types with co(ntra)variant type parameters. Perhaps address directly the examples I've given in my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you hard-code the type, like `PartialFunction[Any,Nothing]`, you cannot restrict your function to take a more specific parameter than `Any`.

By using a generic type parameter, you can end up with a more flexible satisfying all cases and especially making the function safe.

Let's assume you want a function aiming to take an `Animal` as parameter and returning an `Integer`.

Let's assume that function is declared as being:

```
def myFunction: PartialFunction[Any,Nothing]
```

Firstly, PartialFunction would not be specialized to `Animal` at parameter side but to `Any`. What about if I pass a `Human` as parameter...., it would pass.. What about safety?

Secondly, If this function is declared as returning `Nothing`, you can't return from it any value but `Nothing`! Indeed, `Nothing` subclasses all classes in Scala.
This leads to the known rule that return type parameter must always be covariant in order to make a function interesting, not the case with `Nothing`.

In fact, `Nothing` is interesting only when dealing with the `empty` method of `PartialFunction`. Logic since an empty `PartialFunction` by definition involves nothing to return and should be forced to do it :)

You would ask: "So why don't we change the return type to `Any`?"
Answer: Because you'd lose all the benefit of generic erasure time making compiler to add needed casts automatically => You wouldn't retrieve directly the Integer value, but Any. annoying..

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer and include some examples?

Comment: Updated with more explanation.

Comment: I feel that it still doesn't answer my question. Of course, there is no meaning in declaring a function that does something as `PartialFunction[Any,Nothing]`. But that wasn't what I asked for. My question is: why don't we declare the single one `empty` function with this type? It doesn't read any input and never returns a value. So having its type `[Any,Nothing]` is perfectly safe. Furthermore, because of co(ntra)variance, it is automatically casted to any type `[A,B]` for any `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source of `PartialFunction` [available here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L1) we can see that it in fact calls a private method on the `PartialFunction` object:

`private[this] val empty_pf: PartialFunction[Any, Nothing]`

So the return type of empty will always be `PartialFunction[Any, Nothing]`. As for the reasoning behind I have no idea. Maybe someone else have better insight as to why. You could try the language mailing list as well...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that Scala standard library has some more places where generic type parameter is redundant (because of type variance). For example, see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094477/whats-the-point-of-generic-type-in-foreach) about `foreach`. My guess, based on @Peter's answer, is that these redundant generics make the interface more clear. Thanks to them, we don't have to remember which types are covariant, contravariant and invariant. Also, this makes things way simpler for people who are not familiar with variance, which is rather an advanced feature of Scala.

Comment: Thanks, `foreach` is another nice example.